# Not able to read merge fields from docx file using docx4j

Tags: java, xml-parsing, docx, docx4j, mailmerge

I am using [this example](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/FieldsMailMerge.java)   to get all the merge fields using docx4j

While using this I am getting below exception.

I am using docx4j 3.1.0 version . I also used [same file](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/test/resources/MERGEFIELD.docx) given in the example .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class 
org.apache.xml.serializer.ExtendedContentHandler from class 
org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1233)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1060)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1268)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1251)
at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.transform(XmlUtils.java:992)
at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.transform(XmlUtils.java:883)
at org.docx4j.model.fields.FieldsPreprocessor.complexifyFields(FieldsPreprocessor.java:94)
at org.docx4j.model.fields.merge.MailMerger.performMerge(MailMerger.java:385)
at com.test.word.FieldsMailMerge.main(FieldsMailMerge.java:84)
```

Comment: Which version of Xalan is on your classpath?

Comment: And serializer?  Please provide details about your environment ie is this in an IDE, app server? How is your classpath configured?

Comment: issue solved. i created new project with only this class. now no exceptions :) but how can i read all the merge fields?